# Module Secure Page for SSL: from https to http lose session

Tags: users, commerce, ssl

I have a problem:

I work on Drupal 7 with Drupal [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) (Kickstart2 distribution). I have installed the module [SecurePage](https://www.drupal.org/project/securepages) to manage which pages are under https and which under http, I want under ssl only:

- user/*
- checkout/*
- admin/*

I follow this help :  [FOLLOW LINK](https://drupalcommerce.org/comment/1999#comment-1999)

The problem is that if I switch from one page in **https** to one page in **http**, I lose the session, the same problem occurs in the registration steps, after the user registration are complete the user will be redirected to the homepage of the shop, with no messages system like "`Check in your email etc ...`"

Does anyone have a solution for this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried installing the dev version along with the 2 core patches? That always works for me. I get exactly what you describe every time I try to use the 'stable' version.

Comment: With recent Google SEO updates it is considered better practice to SSL your entire site. If that sounds like something you want to do, then you should be able to edit your setting.php file and set $conf['HTTPS'] = TRUE;

Comment: Ok i have changed version (from beta2 to bet2dev) and apply core patch and it work!
Ty very much

Comment: @FatGuyLaughing i dont think is a good practice SSL entire site, cache system under ssl is not friendly (u can use authcache if u are a luky guys) and u decrease performance. I think that SecurePage is the way.

Comment: @commodoreforce If Google get their way (and they usually do) we'll all be on https before too long. Mandating TLS is actually a hotly debated topic in the development of HTTP/2 at the moment; up until recently it was to be mandated, but there will now be an optional unencrypted mode. Still, it's definitely the way things are going